# Pressing the space bar in a text input is causing the parent element to scroll instead of inputting the value

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, css-position

I currently have an issue where a space bar keydown is not being inputted to the text input, but causing the parent element to scroll (when the page height is small enough that scrolling is required). I've noticed that the value is properly inputted when my mouse is away from the parent element or the page height is large enough that scrolling isn't required.

I'm using perfect-scrollbar.js for the styling/functionality of the scrolling and the parent container has a fixed position.

Any help is much appreciated :)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QPKth/1/)

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <div id="sidebar-container">
        <div class="smallbox"></div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Press a letter and then Spacebar" style="width:270px;">
        <div class="largebox"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Appending some code would be advisable as it might help diagnose the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try creating a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The perfectScrollbar function seems to add an event handler to some key events. You have to use `e.stopPropagation` to prevent the execution of other event handlers.

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QPKth/2/) Try the demo with and without `e.stopPropagation()` and you'll see the difference.

```
function keydownHandler(e) {

    //NEW
    var evt = e ? e : window.event;
    if (evt.stopPropagation)    evt.stopPropagation();
    if (evt.cancelBubble!=null) evt.cancelBubble = true;
    //END

    switch(String.fromCharCode(e.which)) {
    case menu.visible.key:
        if (menu.visible.enable==true && e.shiftKey && e.ctrlKey) 
            sendRequest({action:'visible'});
        break;
    case menu.selected.key:
        if (menu.selected.enable==true && e.shiftKey && e.ctrlKey) 
            sendRequest({action:'selected'});
        break;
    case menu.entire.key:
        if (menu.entire.enable==true && e.shiftKey && e.ctrlKey) 
            sendRequest({action:'entire'});
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You sir, are amazing. Fixed it perfectly. If I had enough reputation I would upvote haha. Edit: apparently I do now :)